# how to print only the integer in number of days

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following code which prints the number of days as "8 days, 0:00:00",i only want to print the digit,output should be only "8",can anyone provide inputs on how to do that?

```
from datetime import datetime, date

def main ():
    cr_date = '2013-11-01'
    curr_date = '2013-11-09 18:17:53.196126'
    crdate = date(*map(int, cr_date.split("-")))
    currdate = datetime.strptime(curr_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    days = currdate.date() - crdate
    print "DAYS: " + str(days)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print "DAYS: " + str(days.days)
DAYS: 8
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the whole number of days from a [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta) object, just reference the `days` data:

```
print 'Days: {}'.format(days.days)
Days: 8
```